# Command Syntax not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know this is right but, it says:

> Undetermined object at Column 1 Line 217

Here's the command:

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"[","color":"white"},{"text":"Gateman","color":"dark_aqua"},{"text":"]","color":"white"},{"text":" You need $5 to enter the town.","color":"dark_aqua"},{"text":" >>>","color":"white","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/setblock 3.5 100 -16.5 minecraft:redstone_block}]
```

Comment: If this is right, can you run it on it's own?

Comment: I have absouletely no idea what is wrong. I'm pretty new to command blocks but according to a guide I looked up, it's right.

Comment: It's running on a testfor thing and I know that it's activating.

Comment: **Please** stop adding answers into your questions.

Comment: When was I answering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from here:

```
        "clickEvent":{
            "action":"run_command",
            "value":"/setblock 3.5 100 -16.5 minecraft:redstone_block

    }
]
```

The `value` string, starting at `"/setblock..."`, has not been ended with another quotation mark, `"`, and the `clickEvent` compound tag has not been ended with a closing curly bracket, `}`.

This is the fixed command:

```
 /tellraw @p ["",{"text":"[","color":"white"},{"text":"Gateman","color":"dark_aqua"},{"text":"]","color":"white"},{"text":" You need $5 to enter the town.","color":"dark_aqua"},{"text":" >>>","color":"white","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/setblock 3.5 100 -16.5 minecraft:redstone_block"}}]
```

Comment: Thank you! I used a generator to figure it out it, but that helps! :D